# Good examples of \tl_case:Nn(TF) and \str_case:nn(TF)

Tags: programming, expl3, latex3

While learning `expl3`, I'm having a hard time in using `\str_case:nn(TF)` and `\tl_case:Nn(TF)`. I failed to find good examples online. (E.g., the ones in [`unravel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/unravel) are too complicated for me.) Could you provide self-contained, concise, useful examples of applying `\tl_case:Nn(TF)` and `\str_case:nn(TF)` for demonstration purposes? Let us tackle

1. `\tl_case:NnTF`
2. `\str_case:nnTF`
3. `\str_case_e:nnTF`

first. I got them from http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf.
If you wish to provide examples for other suffixes such as :cnTF, :Nn, etc., please feel free.

Comment: `c` and `N` is just the same thing, and `TF` stands for TrueFalse, if only `F` is present, then it means that only the false franch will be takein into account when needed. So you actually have hree commands `\tl_case:NnTF` and `\str_case:nnTF` and `\str_case_x:nnTF` (the latter two, coming from the same command).

Comment: @Manuel Isn't it that `N` expects a macro name e.g. `\macro` and `c` expects the command sequence name e.g. `macro` without the backslash?

Comment: @cfr Of course, I meant that they are in the end the same function, he hada a longer list befor he edited in which he listed `c` and `N` as different functions. I tried to say that they are not different in functionality, apart from the fact than one works like `\tl_case:Nn \l_tmpa_tl` and the other `\tl_case:cn { l_tmpa_tl }`.

Comment: I've tidied up the links here are removed the bit about the typo: that's not really part of the question and I'll fix in the sources.

Comment: @Manuel Ah, that makes sense. I didn't see the original version of the question.

Comment: @MarkMcGregor I couldn't find a typo and now I think I understand why! These functions are `\str_case_x:nn(TF)` where the `T` and `F` branches do not both have to be given, so `\str_case_x:nnT`, `\str_case_x:nnF` and `\str_case_x:nnTF` all exist, which is why we tend to talk about them as `(TF)` and why in the docs the `TF` is in italics.

Comment: @MarkMcGregor Oh, I see what you mean: fixed in our development version, will update on CTAN soon (this week).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is only a demonstration of applying `\str_case:nnTF`, `\str_case_e:nn` and `\tl_case:nnTF`.

The cases for `:cnTF` etc. have been explained already in comments to the question.

The difference between `\str_case_e` and `\str_case` is the expansion of arguments. The difference between a `\tl..` and `\str..` is that for a string the catcodes of the characters are all equal (12), except those of space characters, which still have the code of 10, whereas in a token list, the catcodes are preserved.

The `\foo:nnTF` versions just enter the conditional branch into input stream -- it is possible to use the matching brackets `{foobar}{...}` for further processing or setup (or 'typesetting') or shift this to TF- branch.

I personally use the `\foo:nn` only and can't remember that I needed `\foo:nnTF` so far, but this depends on the real use-case, of course.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\newcommand{\strcase}[1]{%
  \str_case:nn {#1} {
    {TeX} {\use:c{#1}\space is\space the\space predecessor\space of\space \LaTeX}
    {LaTeX} {\use:c{#1}\space is\space the\space successor\space of\space \TeX}
  }
}

\newcommand{\strcasetf}[3]{%
  \str_case:nnTF {#1} {
    {TeX} {\use:c{#1}\space is\space the\space predecessor\space of\space \LaTeX}
    {LaTeX} {\use:c{#1}\space is\space the\space successor\space of\space \TeX}
    {Word} {#1\space is\space a\space 'typesetter'}
  }{
    \space#2
  }{
    \space#3
  }
}

\newcommand{\genericstrcase}[3]{%
  \str_case:nn {#3} {
    {#1} {It was the first argument}
    {#2} {It was the second argument}
    {Other} {#1 it was 'other'}
  }
}


\newcommand{\strcasextf}[3]{%
  \str_case_e:nnTF {#1} {
    {TeX} {\use:c{#1}\space is\space the\space predecessor\space of\space \LaTeX}
    {LaTeX} {\use:c{#1}\space is\space the\space successor\space of\space \TeX}
    {Word} {#1\space is\space a\space 'typesetter'}
  }{
    \space#2
  }{
    \space#3
  }
}

\tl_new:N \l_tl_one
\tl_new:N \l_tl_two

\newcommand{\tlcase}[3]{%
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tl_one {#1}
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tl_two {#2}

\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#3}

\tl_case:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {
  {\l_tl_one} {Yes,\space it\space was\space #1}
  {\l_tl_two}  {Yes,\space it\space was\space #2}
}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\LaTeXStr}{LaTeX}
\newcommand{\WordPressString}{WordPress}
\newcommand{\WordString}{Word}


\begin{document}

\strcase{TeX}

\strcase{LaTeX}

\strcasetf{LaTeX}{-- the strings match}{-- the strings does not match!}

\strcasetf{Word}{-- the strings match}{-- the strings does not match!}

\strcasetf{WordPress}{-- the strings match}{-- the strings does not match!}

\textbf{Compare}

\strcasetf{\LaTeXStr}{-- the strings match}{-- the strings does not match!}

\strcasextf{\LaTeXStr}{-- the strings match}{-- the strings does not match!}

\tlcase{LaTeX}{TeX}{LaTeX}
\tlcase{LaTeX}{TeX}{\LaTeX} % Does nothing, since \LaTeX is not expanded

\textbf{Comparing command tokens}

\tlcase{\LaTeX}{TeX}{\LaTeX}% Compares again

\tlcase{LaTeX is very nice}{TeX}{LaTeX is very nice} 
\tlcase{TeX is nice}{TeX is not outdated}{TeX is very nice} % Does not match

\textbf{Comparing strings}

\genericstrcase{LaTeX}{TeX}{LaTeX}

\genericstrcase{ #LaTeX}{ #TeX}{ #TeX}

\genericstrcase{\LaTeX}{TeX}{\LaTeX}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the only thing missing is some example where using `\tl_case:Nn` is logical and not `\str_case:nn`. The difference between `\str_case_x:nn` and `\str_case:nn` is clear (and may be point out why the `x` is not `\str_case:xx`). Ah, and you can use `~` rather than `\space` :)

Comment: @Manuel: Thanks, I know about `~` (I used it here already, and it was edited to be `\space` ;-)) I will add some explanations later on

Comment: @MarkMcGregor: Well, I am no native speaker ;-) What do you mean by reusing it? Coding with `expl3` does usually occur on real use-cases, not on 'toy' - demonstration boxes.

Comment: @MarkMcGregor: Well, that's not my job, I am not part of the LaTeX3 team. The `interface3.pdf` is designed to be more of a reference file than an real user manual. Perhaps there are plans to provide document for `expl3` beginners.